# angular CacheFactory doesn't set any value

Tags: angularjs, cachefactory

I'm having issue with CacheFactory module and the problem is that It does not set anything!

here is my code,  logically when the first time the code is run, the second time when I refresh the page it should show me the value but it doesn't and it's always '**undefined**'

```
function ItemFcy($http,$q,CacheFactory) {
  var Items={};
  var factory = {
    getItems: Get
  };
  return factory;

  function Get() {
    var cache= CacheFactory.get('ItemsCache');
    console.log("Cache value is:"+cache);
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/items.json')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        Items= data;
        CacheFactory.createCache('ItemsCache',Items);
        deferred.resolve(Sliders);
        return deferred.promise;
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error on loading items");
      })
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

it always print

> Cache value is:undefined

why it doesn't set anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using `localStorage` rather than `cacheFoactory`

[ng-storage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) might be helpful for you.

Comment: And how should I do that?